# Why EF doesn't create second foreign key column in SQL table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, entity-framework

I'm trying to create an entity (Link) that is related to two other entities (Domain, Subpage) so Link Table will have two columns ID and SubpageID. Basically I'm trying to create 2 one-to-many relationship where Domain object and Subpage object can be mapped to many Link objects and each Link object is related only to one Domain and Subpage object.

**Link model**

```
 public class Link
    {
        [Key]
        public int LinkID { get; set; }

        ...

        [Required]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public virtual Domain Domain { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int SubpageID { get; set; }
        public virtual Subpage Subpage { get; set; }
    }
```

**Domain model**

```
public class Domain
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        ...

        ICollection<Link> Links { get; set; }
    }
```

**Subpage model**

```
 public class Subpage
    {
        [Key]
        public int SubpageID { get; set; }

        ...

        [Required]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public virtual Domain Domain { get; set; }

        ICollection<Link> Links { get; set; }

    }
```

**DbContext**

```
public class DomainAppContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Domain> Domains { get; set; }
        public DbSet<RegInfo> RegInfos { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Subpage> Subpages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Link> Links { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        }

    }
```

**After resolving problems with Cascade Delete etc. I've noticed that Link Table doesn't have an SubpageID column** and I have no idea why...

How can I force EF to create SubpageID column on Link table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i've tried your code with EF 4.3 and 6.01 and the fields where created without problems. You can try to do the following thing.
First of all you should declare your two ICollection Links as public. Than inside the **OnModelCreating** you should add the following code

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Link>()
            .HasRequired(p => p.Subpage)
            .WithMany(l => l.Links)
            .HasForeignKey(k => k.SubpageID);

modelBuilder.Entity<Link>()
            .HasRequired(p => p.Domain)
            .WithMany(l => l.Links)
            .HasForeignKey(k => k.ID);
```

This should force your relationship